# what is BOOL WINAPI return type

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I came across a function definition in c++ as follows: ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx))

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProcessMemoryInfo(
  _In_   HANDLE Process,
  _Out_  PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS ppsmemCounters,
  _In_   DWORD cb
);
```

What is the return type here. Is it `BOOL WINAPI` or `BOOL`? Where is this type defined?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`BOOL` is a typedef for `int`. `WINAPI` is a macro specifying the calling convention (__stdcall, __cdecl etc.) of the function.

```
typedef int BOOL;
#define WINAPI __stdcall
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

It's basically equivalent to:

```
int __stdcall ...
```